# How can I identify an argument as a year in Perl?

Tags: perl, date

I have created a file *argument.pl* which takes several arguments first of which should be in form of a year For example: `2010 23 type`. Here 2010 is a year

my code does something like:

```
use strict;
use warning
use Date::Calc qw(:all);
my ($startyear, $startmonth, $startday) = Today();
my $weekofyear = (Week_of_Year ($startyear,$startmonth,$startday))[0];
my $Year = $startyear;
...
...

if ($ARGV[0])
{
$Year = $ARGV[0];
}
```

Here this code fills `$Year` with "current year" if `$ARGV[0]` is null or doesn't exist.
What do I use here instead of `if ($ARGV[0])`?

Is it possible to check that the value in `$ARGV[0]` is a valid year (like 2010, 1976,1999 etc.)?

Comment: There is no good answer to this. Any integer number except 0 is a valid year in the Gregorian/Julian calender. What you probably want is knowing whether or not that year is in a certain range.

Comment: To provide a good check, you need to add some domain specific information. Which year ranges are valid for your problem? Does it have to be in a certain calendar, or do you want to allow the Hebrew, Muslim, or Chinese calendars. That is, a valid year is exactly what you say it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple test for defined-ness and 4-digits format:

```
$Year = $ARGV[0] if defined $ARGV[0] && $ARGV[0] =~ /^\d{4}$/);
```

Comment: but this passes any 4 number digit.

Comment: Any four digit number is a valid year. So are any 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, and 8 digit numbers. Some calendars are a bit older than the Gregorian or Julian ones. :)

Answer (score 3):

@OP, since you are using Date::Calc, looking at the documentation, you might want to try using some of the functions such as `check_date()` eg

```
check_date
      if (check_date($year,$month,$day))
```

if your year is not correct, the function should give you an error.

Comment: in this case user will input only year, can you please elaborate on how to use above method ? like:


 if (check_date($year)).........gives an error though

Comment: if you only want to check the year, one way is to give `$month` and `$day` a fix value. Pls do check the documentation to see if there are options to check only year.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend ditching positional arguments and using a command line argument processing library such as [Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) so that your program can be called as

```
$ argument.pl -y 2013 -d 23 -t type
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following to ensure the first argument is of the format 19xx or 20xx.

```
if ($ARGV[0] =~/^(19|20)\d{2}$/) {
 $Year = $ARGV[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

give it a try, to find the year is 20** or 19**

```
if ($ARGV[0] =~ m!^((?:19|20)\d\d)) {
$year = $ARGV[0];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or just use 2 digits for the last 2 digits of the year. What could go wrong?